# Can we see what an employer would see when they look at our CV?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

[This section of the About says](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about):

> ### Why is this better than other job sites?
>
> **Hiring managers** can find great developers, see what they’ve done, and *even check out the answers they’ve written on Stack Overflow*. Unlike traditional resumes, a Stack Overflow CV gives hiring managers insight into a developer’s real work and skills instead of a meaningless list of acronyms. *(Emphasis Added)*

#### Question

Can we see what a potential employer would see when they click on our CV? Specifically, how all of the information is displayed? If they're being shown information from our Stack Overflow profile, it's in our interest to know what they see.

Comment: +1. Also, I'd like the option to replace everything they see with a picture of a giant laser for the next 20 minutes, even if they leave the website or, say, go to the washroom. A direct-to-brain interface would really help here. I want to be able to leave a lasting impression of my talents. I think we all do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Agreed entirely.

If I'm going to pay for this service, I want to see **exactly** what the potential employer can see.

I like that we can see exactly how our CV looks in the search results - but is there anything else a potential employer can see? For example - a break down of my answers, upvotes, downvotes in my `Favorite Tags`, etc.

Excellent feature request.

Answer (score 4):

Uh, there's a tab next to Edit called View CV.  It renders all the information with StackOverflow styling.

And at the top, on the right, it lists "Stack Overflow Account" and then your SO Badge.

Comment: Yes this already exists!

Comment: And this is *exactly* what potential employers would see?

Comment: yep. Same control, exactly.

Comment: And Jeff says just above here that the View CV is exactly what your looking for.

Comment: @seanmonstar : It is indeed my fault for not being 'clear' about my question; but see the new question for what I was driving at. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25201/will-employers-get-a-special-view-of-our-stack-overflow-profile

Answer (score 1):

The impression I got at Dev Days Boston, when Joel explained it, was that they wouldn't see Stack Overflow stuff on your CV page, but would have a link to your Stack Overflow profile page. For you, they would be brought [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker).

I'm not sure how accurate this is.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that answer. But it makes sense.