# Will employers get a special view of our Stack Overflow Profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

Jeff asked me to [ask this as a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/25103/list).

---

[This section of the About says](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about):

> ### Why is this better than other job sites?
>
> **Hiring managers** can find great developers, see what they’ve done, and *even check out the answers they’ve written on Stack Overflow*. Unlike traditional resumes, a Stack Overflow CV gives hiring managers insight into a developer’s real work and skills instead of a meaningless list of acronyms. *(Emphasis Added)*

[Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) says in a [comment to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/stackoverflow-careers/24903#24903):

> I guess the primary difference is that we feel the free job sites are filled with noise, because they're free. Also **we'll have superior integration in highlighting your SO profile, since we have low-level access to the API and DB**. – Jeff Atwood♦ 23 hours ago *(emphasis added)*

---

#### Questions

1. How will our Stack Overflow Profile be displayed?
2. How will it be shown in relation to our CV?

Presently it's just a link, but if and when that changes, it'd be a good feature to allow us to see the integration of the two as they would see it when they browse the careers site.

If they're being shown information from our Stack Overflow profile, it's in our interest to know what they see and how they see it.

Comment: They get ponies!

Comment: When TheTXI et. al. talk about waffles, it makes me really crave waffles. I'm just glad ponies aren't edible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employers will see your StackOverflow signature (name, reputation, picture, and badge counts) right on the search results page.

Currently we're expecting that employers will search, see a bunch of candidates, and click through on the ones who look like they might be good fits. After they've clicked through to a bunch of them, they'll check little boxes on the ones they want to approach. This will give them an email form where they can compose an email to the job seeker explaining who they are and what they're hiring for.

Once this stuff is actually working, we'll put up screenshots.

Comment: Would you include the ability to see Top *n* answers in their 'Favorite' listed technologies?

Comment: What expansions are in the pipeline?  Will there ever be the option to upload a "side attached" Resume/CV?  Will there ever be the option to add additional open source projects, manually, that the system isn't auto-detecting properly (e.g., from Github)?